# Retrieving escaped JSON string from PHP webservice in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I'm trying to retrieve some HTML to be inserted into a web page from a web service, I have a database of HTML which relates to different applications so i'm selecting the ID of the application and returning them in JSON to the javascript front end, the problem i'm getting is the first two numeric values get parsed fine, but the CSS/JS/HTML elements don't - i'm guessing its to do with the way the string is escaped but i'm not sure how to handle it?

```
[{"id":"1","machine_id":"1","CSS":"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text\/css\" href=\"newcss.css\">","JavaScript":"<script src=\"js\/SlotMachine.js\" type=\"text\/javascript\"><\/script>,<script src=\"js\/jquery-1.11.1.min.js\" type=\"text\/javascript\"><\/script>","HTML":"<div class=\"outer_container\">\n                          <div class=\"reelcasing\">\n                            <canvas id=\"reel1\" width=\"150\" height=\"400\"><\/canvas>\n                          <\/div>\n                          <div class=\"reelcasing\">  \n                            <canvas id=\"reel2\" width=\"150\" height=\"400\"><\/canvas>\n                          <\/div>\n                          <div class=\"reelcasing\">\n                            <canvas id=\"reel3\" width=\"150\" height=\"400\"><\/canvas>\n                          <\/div>\n                          <input type=\"button\" id=\"start\" class=\"start_button\" value=\"Press Start\">\n                        <\/div>","rollSpeed":"25","rollIncrement":"20"}]
```

Then i'm doing:

```
$http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'http://localhost/api/machine/get/' + machineId
          }).success(function(data){
                  $scope.machineDetails = data;

                  // Debugging
                  for(machine in data){
                      alert(machine.id);                      
                  }

          }).error(function(){
              alert("Unable to retrieve slot machine information.");
          });
        };
```

UPDATE
To clarify the values from the JSON get read in except where they've got the complex html, for example that example returns:

```
machineDetails: [
0: {
id: 1
machine_id: 1
CSS:
JavaScript: ,
HTML:
```

Edit:

Ok well its odd if I step through the data using...

```
        angular.forEach(data, function(data, key){
            console.log(data.CSS); 
         });
```

It gives the correct values however if I do:

```
$scope.machineDetails = data;
```

It fills in the ID and machineID but doesn't put any of the HTML stuff in, its not a massive issue but i'd like to know why it won't store it in scope?

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: Hmm thats throwing an error, lemmy look into a min, be right bacl!

Comment: Yeah thats odd i've checked the JSON is valid via JSON lint, but I get an error when I do $scope.machineDetails = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: what error you gets ?

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at http://localhost/Ang/js/SlotMachine.js:39:48
    at http://localhost/Ang/js/angular.min.js:80:82
    at http://localhost/Ang/js/angular.min.js:110:390
    at k.$eval (http://localhost/Ang/js/angular.min.js:124:250)
    at k.$digest (http://localhost/Ang/js/angular.min.js:121:332)
    at k.$delegate.__proto__.$digest (<anonymous>:844:31)
    at k.$apply (http://localhost/Ang/js/angular.min.js:125:12)
    at k.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (<anonymous>:855:30)
    at n (http://localhost/Ang/js/angular.min.js:80:374)

Comment: Actually i'm using Angular to get the JSON object so it should be decoded already?

Comment: should work fine , provide a demo that replicates your problem

Comment: try https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: k two mins guys thanks for the help..

Comment: _“for example that example returns”_ – how does this particular output get generated? That: `JavaScript: ,` looks like perhaps the `<script>` elements _does_ get output after the `JavaScript: `, but you don’t _see_ it because the browser parses this whole debug output as HTML …?

Comment: Hmm thats an interesting point, i'm using the AngularJS debugger, you may have hit the nail on the head...

Comment: Yep you got it who'da thunk it, the debugger actually works off HTML....